# How to find total change in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe in the form of:

```
Date        Time   station   num_bikes  num_racks
01/10/18    3.02   Girwood   5           6   
01/10/18    3.03   Girwood   6           5 
01/10/18    3.04   Girwood   2           9
01/10/18    3.05   Girwood   9           2 
12/08/18    4.10   Fraser    0           14 
12/08/18    4.11   Fraser    1           13 
12/08/18    4.12   Fraser    0           14          
03/09/18    10.10  Carslile  2           8
03/09/18    10.11  Carslile  4           6
03/09/18    10.12  Carslile  0           10
24/09/18    10.10  Girwood   9           3
24/09/18    10.11  Girwood   10          2
24/09/18    10.12  Girwood   4           8
```

The variable "num_bikes" is the number of bikes present at the station in the specified date and time "num_racks" is the empty racks available at the station in the specified date and time.I have data for every second over 3 months and I want to be able to determine the  number of arrivals of bikes and the number of departures of bikes from each station in each month.

I would like the output to look like:

```
Station     Month     Arrivals  Departures
Girwood     August    5         2   
Fraser      August    1         1 ie
Girwood     September 1         6 ie   
Girwood     October   3         4 ie 
Carslile    September 2         4 ie
```

Comment: maybe you will need `groupby(['station', 'date'])` and maybe `shift()` to compare values in adjacent rows

Comment: Could you please Post sample of expected output and let us know then?

Comment: does that help? the values are just rough

Comment: You need to correct your expected output and your sample data; it is not correct. Also, for each month and station in your sample data the num_bikes always increases so arrivals would increases and departures would be zero for every single station. Bikes are only returned in this sample dataset and never leave the station.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output still does not match the data in your sample dataset and as far as I can tell is not correct. I think this is what you are trying to accomplish but am not 100% sure.

```
# convert date to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

# create month col
df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month_name()

# create a copy so you are not updating the original df
df2 = df.copy()

# groupby and calc the diff
df2['diff'] = df2.groupby(['month', 'station'])[['num_bikes']].diff()

# sum all positive numbers as arrivals because every time the num_bikes increases it is an arrival
# sum all negative numbers as departures because every time the num_bikes decreases it is an departure
df2[['month', 'station', 'diff']].groupby(['month', 'station'])['diff'].agg([('arrivals' , lambda x : x[x > 0].sum()),
                                       ('departures' , lambda x : abs(x[x < 0].sum()))])


                    arrivals  departures
month     station                       
August    Fraser         1.0         1.0
October   Girwood        8.0         4.0
September Carslile       2.0         4.0
          Girwood        1.0         6.0
```